# unexpected SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas even if we use .loc method

Tags: pandas, data-analysis, missing-data

```
workclass = X_train[~X_train['workclass'].isnull()]['workclass'].unique()
for dataset in [X_train, X_test]:
    df = dataset[dataset['workclass'].isnull()].index
    size = len(df)
    s = pd.Series([workclass[np.random.randint(0, 8)] for _ in range(size)], index=df, dtype=object)
    dataset.loc[:, 'workclass'] = dataset.loc[:, 'workclass'].fillna(s)
```

Output

```
S:\AnacondaPF\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:965: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

The last line is giving me `SettingWithCopyWarning` even if i use the `.loc` method.
Even it is giving the warning it has filled all the missing values in the two datasets.

Can anyone explanin why?

Comment: How working if change `dataset.loc[:, 'workclass'] = dataset.loc[:, 'workclass'].fillna(s)` to `dataset['workclass'] = dataset['workclass'].fillna(s)` ?

Comment: `dataset['workclass'] = dataset['workclass'].fillna(s)`?

Comment: It is still giving me the same warning

Comment: @Anonymous it will have to do with whatever `s` is.

Comment: @DavidErickson as you can see `s` is a normal series

Comment: @Anonymous it's hard to tell without being able to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have used the `train_test_split` from `sklearn` so to split the data before.

The pandas will raise the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning if it is not sure that the given DataFrame you are changing is either a copy or the original DataFrame.

The causes for the `SettingWithCopyWarning` are explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/14180790) and the [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8723).

You can just take the warning like a false positive warning or you can suppress the warning by doing this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y) # X = features y = labels
X_train, X_test = X_train.copy(), X_test.copy()
```